# Size of image to set as Background image in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

I am trying to put a background image on a `UIViewController`.However i cannot figure out the size needed because the image should support devices from **iphone 4s** to **iPAD**...Here are few questions:

1) Should i put those large image on image xcassets on 1x,2x,3x size,if so what should be the size of those images?

2) Or Should i Copy a high resolution image on the bundle itself again if so what should be the size?

Comment: Please follow "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483934/how-to-handle-iphone-screen-sizes-resolution-for-background-images/48563225#48563225"

Answer (score 0):

We have differnet-2 sizes in assets like here:

[image]

(Only for iPhones)
What I found is that, you should opt for first option and 750X1333, 1080X1920 and 1242X2208 should be the 1x,2x and 3x.

You can add more by clicking on tick sign and give sizes like above we give for the iPhones.

Designer will give you proper sizes with respect to resolution to each ipad and iphone

Comment: @Costello If you want exact images resolution to be fit in each device then you need to give them separately otherwise, the image will pixelate/stretch a bit.

Comment: @Costello was this helpful or did you find any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what kind of image you want to display

- If it's a solid or pattern image that won't have any different if scaling up / down then I suggest that you put it in image xcassets and use for all supported devices. You should put the largest size image, you can find all screensizes from this: http://iosres.com/
- Otherwise, if it's a picture with details like a portrait or food dish, etc. You have to drop it manually with some photo editors like photoshop then add it to xcassets separately for iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help:

```
var backGroundImageView :UIImageView! //declare 
///set image contentMode in viewDidLoad()
self.backGroundImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

However, you should check whether the image is in landscape or portrait orientation.
Image xcassets on @1x,@2x,@3x size will match iPhone 4S screen size automatically, @2x is for the iPhone 5, @3x for the Plus.
As for the iPad you can check the Apple Developers documents.

Answer (score 0):

In place of 1x,2x & 3x images take single  PDF image and place in  image assets it ll fit for all comparability devices.